# Device manager - multiple Android devices, fails to use ADB

Tags: android, windows, adb

When i connect my Android device ( which is in usb debug mode ) i get multiple entry's in my device manager.
The ADB does not recognize any device then so i change the driver to Android composite ADB Interface at random of 1 of the 3 it can find the device as intended. However during my process i need to swap to the ADB bootloader interface if i change the same drover it can not find the device anymore. Changeing now the other 2 also to ADB bootloader fails aswell. So i try'd to adb kill-server in a new prompt but without succes.

Do u maybe have advice what to do to show only 1 device again in Device manager?
maybe then it always selects the right one.

Thank you!

see above for a bit detail.

- change 3/3 driver
- other usb port

Comment: Based on your description it seems that you are on Windows. How many devices you see depends on what USB options are set on the device (adb active, USB file-sharing active) and what driver you have installed. The best way to get an overview is selecting a device that belongs to your phone and then switch view mode to "Devices by connection", then you see all devices. If you misconfigured something you can still delete the devices in the tree of your phone below "generic USB hub" so next time Windows will try to automatically select the correct driver.

Comment: HI Robert, thank you for your help.  i am indeed on windows. i have try'd them one by one but unfortunately none of 3 will show with adb devices anymore. i have disabled them one by one to test this. So i try'd a other device and cabels but i keep getting the same thing.

Comment: Do not disable devices, delete them and next time you reconnect the device Windows will detect it new and hopefully assign the correct drivers.